# Whatsapp Profile View implementation

Tags: android, whatsapp

When you view someones profile on Whatsapp, the screen is divided into 2 sections. The actual picture, and the options below. When u "pull" the picture down, it slides down to fill about 3/4 of the screen, but when you "push" it up, the part where the picture is displayed fades into an ActionBar and the options fill the screen(in what seems to be a VerticleScrollView). My question is, how do you implement that functionality? what combination of components are being used and how?

Comment: Google appbarlayout

Comment: appbarlayout inside a coordinatorlayout.Thank u sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CollapsingToolbarLayout` . Example xml structure like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/profileactivity_appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme3.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/profileactivity_collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/profileactivity_fullimage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```